# nanoHTTPD - How to run as a single background thread in Android?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, nanohttpd

My application is to use nanoHTTPD as an alternative to pressing buttons and keying in text on an Android UI for automation and regression test  I currently have a main UI thread and a customized nanoHTTPD running in a different thread.  Consider each HTTP request will be serviced very quickly in the UI thread.  I think my model could be simplified if I could force nanoHTTPD to NOT start a new thread for each incoming request.  I would not mind the blocking I/O model at all for my use cases.  I see there is a pluggable strategy for threading.  Can the below be modified such that only one web request is active at a time (blocking model)?

```
public static class DefaultAsyncRunner implements AsyncRunner {
    private long requestCount;

    @Override
    public void exec(Runnable code) {
        ++requestCount;
        Thread t = new Thread(code);
        t.setDaemon(true);
        t.setName("NanoHttpd Request Processor (#" + requestCount + ")");
        t.start();
    }
}
```

I could probably also do more elaborate message queues but "dumbing-down" to nanoHTTPD in one thread seems simplest.

Comment: I think recent Android versions will not allow network activity on the UI thread.